# Angular Typescript how to use mathematical formula with date object substraction

Tags: typescript, angular9

I am trying the conver the below formula which works in excel in Typescript. Can anyone help me how to achieve this. I am getting `'The left -hand and right hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type'`

```
const result = ((inceptionDate) - 365.25 - referenceInceptionDate) / 365.25 + (riskFactor))
```

FYI: Both inceptionDate and referenceInceptionDate are Date objects.

Tried this and not getting any error. Is this the right way?

```
const result: number = ((inceptionDate.valueOf() - 365.25 - entry.referenceInceptionDate.valueOf()) / 365.25 + (riskFactor));
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to perform calculations on a date object. This is not a native numerical object. You'll need to re-write the code to use something like the [valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) method.

Or if you'll have lots of these types of calculations then consider a date library such as [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).